# Citation is not using the custom prefix defined by multibib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, acm, multibib, acmart

I am writing a paper that I need to have two bibliographies. For example, a regular references pages and another one for a specific topic.
Something like this:[image]

I already did it with multibib.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
%... 
\newcites{New}{The other list}
\begin{document}
%... 

\section{test}
\citep{GM05} this is a test \citeNew{Williams2009} 
% and this as well \citeNew{Gren}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}

\bibliographystyleNew{plain}
\bibliographyNew{references}

\end{document}
```

-- Content of my reference.bib file

```
@article{Williams2009,
author = {Williams, Laurie and Kudrjavets, Gunnar and Nagappan, Nachiappan},
doi = {10.1109/ISSRE.2009.32},
isbn = {9780769538785},
title = {{On the Effectiveness of Unit Test Automation at Microsoft 1}},
year = {2009}
}

@article{Gren,
author = {Gren, Lucas and Antinyan, Vard},
title = {{On the Relation Between Unit Testing and Code Quality}}
}
```

-- Content of my sample-bibliography.bib file

```
@article{GM05,
author = {Williams, Laurie and Kudrjavets, Gunnar and Nagappan, Nachiappan},
doi = {10.1109/ISSRE.2009.32},
isbn = {9780769538785},
title = {{Example}},
year = {2009}
}
```

However, the citation is not correct. I want it to be "**[1] this is a test [New1]**", instead of "**[1] this is a test [1]**"

Comment: I am working with the following template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-new-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt#.WWEi2BMrK1s

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) External templates can change. Please try to make a [minimal but working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) and add it into your question. This would help us to reproduce the problem, test our suggestions and find an answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, I updated my question! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please always test your example. The `...` in the document preamble result in an error message. *Working* means, that the example should be compilable without error message or with only those error messages that are part of the problem. I've commented the line in your example to get a real MWEB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not with `acmart`, but rather with `natbib`.  Here is your example with `article`:

```
%\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,url}
\setcitestyle{numbers,square}
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
%... 
\newcites{New}{The other list}
\begin{document}
%... 

\section{test}
\citep{GM05} this is a test \citeNew{Williams2009} 
% and this as well \citeNew{Gren}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}

\bibliographystyleNew{plainnat}
\bibliographyNew{references}
```

[image]

As a workaround, I would use consecutive numbering instead:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{multibib}
%... 
\newcites{New}{The other list}
\begin{document}
%... 

\section{test}
\citep{GM05} this is a test \citeNew{Williams2009} 
% and this as well \citeNew{Gren}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}

\bibliographystyleNew{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliographyNew{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after two days I finally found a decent solution without any hacks or something like that!