# multibib custom prefixed number for second biblio

Tags: biblatex, natbib, subdividing, multibib

Envornment: macOS 10.13.4, Full 2018 MacTeX distro, TeXworks v0.6.2.

My MWE

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ mbib, web ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@incollection{Akallabeth,
  author       = "Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel",
  title        = "Akallabeth---The Downfall of Numenor",
  year         = 2014,
  editor       = "Tolkien, Christopher",
  booktitle    = "The Silmarillion",
  publisher    = "Mariner Books",
  address      = "New York, USA",
  tags         = "MasterThesis",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{web.bib}
@misc{wikiicd10,
  author       = "Wikipedia",
  title        = "{ICD-10}",
  year         = 2015,
  url          = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10",
  tags         = "master",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,twoside,openright,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{web}{Useful websites}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
% Generate two citation callouts
\citet{Akallabeth},
\citeweb{wikiicd10}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Useful websites}
\bibliographystyleweb{unsrtnat}
\bibliographyweb{web}

\end{document}
```

This works, except that I want the second biblio (which is all Web URLs) to use a letter prefix. IOW, a rendered citation like "...as described [W1]..." with the linked reference numbered 'W1' instead of the more normal '1'.

I've looked at [Natbib-Multibib problem with prefix labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124805/natbib-multibib-problem-with-prefix-labels) and [Citation is not using the custom prefix defined by multibib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379786/citation-is-not-using-the-custom-prefix-defined-by-multibib), both of which make me think this may not be possible. I'm actually using ACMstyling (via ACM-Reference-Format.bst) although the linked article make me think this is a natbib/multibib issues.

I'm using `arara` to compile multiple bibtex passes via TexWorks as each call needs a different target bib file.

Now I've got arara working, I'm happy to try using biblatex/biber if it will give me the output required, although I guess I'll have to write all the styles myself as ACM's style docs aren't Biblatex compatible yet (as at June 2018).

Comment: Note entirely sure why this was downvoted. It seems a perfectly clear question with a very usable MWE and prior research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex` it is not too hard to split the bibliography in two. You don't even need to use two separate `.bib` files (though you can).

Here, we use the two `.bib` files to add the `keyword` `web` to all sources from `\jobname-web.bib` (see [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864)).
You can cite all sources as usual, but the bibliography is split when  we filter by `keyword`. To get the prefix for the Web bibliography we need `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]` (see [Separate bibliographies for phdthesis and mastersthesis in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369309/35864)).

You'll need to be running Biber instead of BibTeX here, [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) (of course arara can do that for you as well).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Akallabeth,
  author       = "Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel",
  title        = "Akallabeth---The Downfall of Numenor",
  year         = 2014,
  editor       = "Tolkien, Christopher",
  booktitle    = "The Silmarillion",
  publisher    = "Mariner Books",
  address      = "New York, USA",
  tags         = "MasterThesis",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-web.bib}
@misc{wikiicd10,
  author       = "Wikipedia",
  title        = "{ICD-10}",
  year         = 2015,
  url          = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10",
  tags         = "master",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-web.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-web.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=web, append]
    }
  }
}



\begin{document}
\cite{Akallabeth} and
\cite{wikiicd10}

\printbibliography[notkeyword=web]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=W]
\printbibliography[keyword=web, title={Web references}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you mention the ACM in your question, I must point out that only very few (if at all, really) publishers can accept `biblatex` submissions. Often the internal workflow of publishers can't really deal with how different `biblatex` bibliographies are to BibTeX bibliographies (one difference being that BibTeX bibliographies are essentially pre-generated ready-to-typeset LaTeX source with only the usual `\emph`, ... markup; while `biblatex` generates the bibliography output on the fly from a raw data format). See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). If you only need to submit a PDF you are in the clear. But don't ignore the submission guidelines when they ask for BibTeX and double check if they can accept `biblatex`. If you template pre-loads `natbib` I see little chance of your submission using `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Based on using your MWE, it seems I don't need arara as biber seems to do both biblios in one pass. Point taken about ACM, but this is my PhD thesis so I get to choose. Still, as biblatex has no defined ACM style I guess I'll need to code those myself or use another style format.

Comment: @mwra Indeed, Biber usually only requires one pass on one file (in weird situations you may need one more pass after LaTeX was run, but that normally only happens if a citation causes another citation - you'll be notified if that is the case in the `.log` file). Of course arara is still a useful tool. `biblatex` does not have as many pre-defined styles available as BibTeX since it is younger and some things are so easily changed that a full style is not called for. For many intents and purposes the standard styles and a few modifications already give good results.

Comment: One small question - what does the `\DeclareSourcemap{}` section of code do? If I try removing it the code still seems to work?

Comment: @mwra It adds the `web` keyword to the entries in the web `.bib` file. This is necessary if your entries don't have the `web` keyword already. Note that the code is for Biber, so you will only see the effect of its removal after a full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX circle.